# Can a facebook app publish to a user's stream without the 'via app_name' tag on the status update?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ideally I'd like the status update to look **exactly** as it would if it was entered directly by the user on their page. Is this possible?

BTW, this isn't a spammy app, and the status would always be posted with the users full knowledge and consent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  This is meant to 1) help advertise your app to additional users and 2) help users know which app to de-authorize and/or avoid if one of them *is* spammy

Comment: So to confirm, having a 'via xxx' tag is enforced? What about the icon? Is there a default text that would appear there if nothing is set?